# GoogleDocs API logic and programming

Tags: logical-operators, google-docs-api, zapier

I want to use a logic in my GoogleDocs Template for Zapier. I just want to do something like

```
{{if strstr(name, “google”)}} hello 

{{/if}}
```

Is that possible or can I just use placeholders like `{{name}}`?

Answer (score 0):

For something that basic, you could capture the original text, use mustache to apply the logic and then rely on the replaceText merge method recommended in the api docs.

```
let requests = [];
let contents = doc.body.content||[];
contents.reverse().forEach(content=>{
  const paragraph = content.paragraph||{};
  const elements = paragraph.elements||[];
  const paragraphContent = elements.reduce((acc, obj)=> { return [...acc, obj.textRun.content]}, []);
  var parts = paragraphContent.join('').match(/{{#(.*?)}}(.*?){{\/(.*?)}}/g)||[];
  parts.forEach((part, index)=>{
    requests.push({      
      replaceAllText: {
        containsText: {
          text: part,
          matchCase: true,
        },
        replaceText: mustache.render(part, objMerge)||'',
      },                
    })
  })
})
```